# How to limit the CRUD content of Rails' current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a task management system and building a user registration and login system without relying on the devise gem. Currently I am facing a challenge, I want each user (called current_user when logging in) can only see the tasks they created (listed on the homepage/index), including that they can only edit or delete their own tasks. To this end, I added a before action `def find_user_task` to the controller, but it is completely invalid. Please tell me, what am I missing in principle?

This is part of TasksController

```
  before_action :find_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :check_login!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :find_user_task, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :publish]

private
  def find_task
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def task_params
    p = params.require(:task).permit(:name, :due_date, :note, :priority)
    p[:status] = params[:task][:status].to_i
    return p
  end

  def find_user_task
        @task = Task.find(params[:id])
        @task = Task.find_by(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)
        # @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

This is part of Model Task

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :note, :due_date, :status, :priority, presence: true
  has_many :category_tasks
  has_many :categories, through: :category_tasks
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true, optional: true
```

This is part of Model User

```
require 'digest'

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 4 }, presence: true
  validates :role, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: do tasks `belong_to` a user?  We do not need the controllers, we need to see the relationships in the models

Comment: @RockwellRice I updated two models' information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope I can help you here...
first of all, here on this piece of code:

```
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task = Task.find_by(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)
```

Your second line overrides the first, so you can remove the first one. About your problem, I would suggest you to do that based on your models and relationships... it's easier (and better) than to handle it in controller. The thing is you wanna make sure that a task belongs to a user (and which can have N tasks). Before you create a task, you make sure to set the user_id for that task as the current_user.id. It would be somthing like that:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
end
```

and for your task model:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then, on your create action on your tasks controller (or wherever you do that), be sure to set the user_id for your current_user:

```
@task.user_id = current_user.id
```

If you still didn't created the foreign_key (user_id) for a task, just make a migration, something like this:

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToTask user_id:integer
rails db:migrate
```

Then, if you do it correctly, you can get the tasks for a specific user just acessing them by the relationship: user.tasks (or, in your case):

```
@tasks = current_user.tasks
```

For debugging and testing that, rails console is your friend... create a task for a user, then check on console if the user_id is set correctly. Then try to load that user.tasks and see if it brings them as you expected. Go checking it step by step.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I have a few questions that I can't figure out. One, I should add ```@task.user_id = current_user.id``` and ```@tasks = current_user.tasks``` to those controller#actions, if I add the previous one to the def index, ```Undifeined methos user_id``` will be encountered.

Comment: Second, the original tasks already have users, but the format is BigDecimal, I changed it to integer. Three, I had tried to replace the current "@task = Task.find_by(id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)" with ```@task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])```, but this would result in ```Couldn't find Task with 'id'=24 [WHERE "tasks"."user_id" = $1]``` error.

Comment: In rails console, when I execute ```User.tasks```, I get ```NoMethodError (undefined method `tasks' for User``` error. If I execute ```u1 = User.find_by_id(1) in sequence ```, then ```u1.tasks``` will get ```#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>```

Comment: how can I merge ```@tasks = @query.result``` and ```@tasks = current_user.tasks.order(id: :desc)```?

Comment: I guess you could force a query like this:  tasks = Task.where(user_id: current_user.id).
But if you set the user_id on a task like (task.user_id = current_user.id), it's still not on the database. You have to do a task.save first, so it would persist on your database

Comment: For your not found error... there's not a Task with id 24 on your database... you should check why. Maybe a Task.all.pluck(&:id) could help

Comment: User.tasks wont' work because in this case you're calling the method directly on the Model, not the instance user object. As you did later, u = User.find() and then u.tasks, it should work. In your case, if your user.id is 1, and its tasks are empty, it's because there's no task with user_id 1. You can also check it with Tasks.all.pluck(&:user_id)

Comment: I don't now what it's your query, but surely you can do that on only one query, merging your logic. In any case, ou can concatenate them using a "+" operator

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved these problems after adding ```@task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)``` in def create.